# Curser position in EditText

Tags: android

I have an EditText that the user can write in,
when the app starts there is already a string in the EditText.
When the user clicks the EditText it becomes focused and the curser is where the user clicked the EditText text box.

I want the the curser will be at the beginning of the EditText regardles to where it was clicked.
How can I set the curser position upon clicking the EditText text box ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the above doesn't work try:

```
    editText.setSelection(1);
    editText.extendSelection(0);
    editText.setSelection(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should achieve what you want:

`editText.setSelection(0)`